# Adding a timer, setting the time with user input and making that a cooldown

Tags: vb.net

I don't know how to get around this, I just need some headers on to do this.
I am trying to make a cooldown system so lets say; the user inputs the 60s then the timer would be set to 60 seconds and when they try to run that function it would check if the timer is running and block them from using it until its over.

I have tried looking at the System.Timer but I just don't understand it, thanks for reading.

Comment: What kind of application are you building?

Comment: Just a personal project, I just really need that cooldown feature.

Comment: I didn't ask what the app is for, but what **kind** of app that is. Desktop (UWP, WPF, WinForms etc.), Web, Mobile. Add the appropriate Tags and show what code you have written for this.

Comment: @Jimi Ohhhh.... My bad - it's a console.

Comment: A Console what? :) .Net Framework, .Net Core, .Net 5...

Comment: @Jimi .Net Framework

Comment: Yep, as mentioned, you have to Tag your question accordingly, don't post the specifics in comments (delete these comments after you have Tagged the question correctly).

Comment: A `Timer` is not appropriate, which is why you can't make sense of it. Use a `Stopwatch`. The `Elapsed` property will tell you how much time has elapsed and you can check whether that is outside your cooldown time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out it suits to you or not

```
Import System.Diagnostics

 Private Sub wait(ByVal interval As Integer)
        Dim sw As New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()
        Do While sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < interval
            ' Allows UI to remain responsive
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        sw.Stop()
    End Sub
```

Comment: This supposes that there's a message loop, where `DoEvents()` makes sense (if it actually makes sense). This is a Console application. So, your method should also be `static` (`Shared`). What remains to do is to test it.

Comment: @jimi Sorry I didn't read it is console application . so I just put code what I am using for windows appplication. And about DoEvents in my application there is lots of timer and serial port access going on so I need to put that .. thanks for suggestion